# How to conditionally update a nested list in DynamoDB if parent might not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table with primary key "customer" and the main entry consisting of a map of locations and a String Set of items the customer purchased at a given place

```
{
    "visits": {
        "M": {
            "location-1": {
                "SS": [
                    "item1",
                    "item2",
                ]
            },
            "location-2": {
                "SS": [
                    "items"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "customer": {
        "S": "cool-customer-id"
    }
}
```

**Task:** I need to upsert a new item, without reading from the DB.

If the customer doesn't exist or if `location-53` doesn't exist in the `visits` map I expect it to create an entry for a specific customer with `visits.location-53` set to a set with one item, "item4".

If it does exist, I would like to append the item to the existing set.

The below update expression works ONLY if there has been a previous entry for a given customer already inserted (PutItem) either for the same or a different location.

```
request := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    ConditionExpression: aws.String("not contains (#visits.#place, :newItem)"),

    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]string{
        "#visits":     "visits",
        "#place":      "location53",
    },

    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]dynamotypes.AttributeValue{
    ":newItem": &dynamotypes.AttributeValueMemberSS{Value: []string{"item4"}},
    },

    Key: map[string]dynamotypes.AttributeValue{
        partitionKeyName: &dynamotypes.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "some-customer-id-here"},
    },

    TableName:                   aws.String("visits"),

    UpdateExpression: aws.String("ADD #visits.#place :newItem"),

}

db.UpdateItem(context.Background(), request)
```

If the entry for a customer is totally empty, it will return:

> ValidationException: The document path provided in the update
> expression is invalid for update

How can I make it always work?

Comment: Where is your actual code calling AWS? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can help us help you :)

Comment: db.UpdateItem(ctx, request_mentioned_above)

Comment: Can you please update your answer with what is the actual question to?

Comment: Does it fail when `#visits.#place` is `null`? Otherwise, if the customer doesn't exist, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want me to update - the specific question is in the topic + at the bottom. 

As per the question, I need it to upsert a new item, i.e. I expect it to create an entry for a specific customer with #visits.location-53 set to a set with one item, "item4", if the customer doesn't exist or if "location-53" doesn't exist in the visits map. If it exits, I would like to append the item to the existing set.

I haven't checked it with #visits.#place set to null, but that wouldn't help, as that would require me to create the entry in the first place.

Comment: `ADD can only be used on top-level attributes, not nested attributes.` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html

Comment: I just edited to add that for you lol check the post history

Comment: oups, did not realise that's possible - sorry!

Comment: "ADD can only be used on top-level attributes, not nested attributes." Well, it does work in all cases except for where there is no parent, so that's not correct...  Also, the same problem appears when using SET ... = list_append, instead of ADD.